# removeClass() срабатывает только один раз

Tags: jquery, css

Есть форма с одним `input`. При `submit`, если `input` пуст, я добавляю к нему эффект подрагивания с помощью соответствующего CSS класса (`.shake`). Эффект `shake` делаю используя CSS Animation и keyframes.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var input = $('input').removeClass('shake');

   if (!input.val()) {
      input.addClass('shake');
   }
})
```

Эффект виден каждый раз когда я присваиваю класс `.shake` к элементу. Поэтому, если `input` уже имеет класс `.shake` (от предыдущих действий), то вначале я его удаляю.

**Проблема:** Удаление и присваивание класса каждый раз происходит как нужно, но эффект видел только один раз. При этом, в режиме отладки скрипта, при пошаговом выполнении все работает хорошо. Эффект виден при каждом нажатии.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: убирайте класс по событию конца анимации

Comment: Убрал класс после конца анимации. Работает !!! Спасибо )